# how do I assert request payload value against response body

Tags: karate

I am trying to assert request payload values into response body.

```
Scenario Outline: Check userIds
Given path '/api/test/'
And request {"userId": <users>,"age": "32"}
When method POST
Then status 201
And match response.userId == request.userId
Examples:
| userId |
|user1|
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
And request {"userId": "#(userId)", "age": "32" }
```

And:

```
And match response.userId == userId
```

Please try to read the docs and examples carefully, you are missing some fundamentals.